# How can I test an overridden GET method in Django CBV?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a django `DetailView` that I've overridden to allow the user to unsubscribe from emails using a query string in the `get` method:

```
  class MemberProfileView(DetailView):                                                  
      template_name = "profile.html"                                                    
      model = Member                                                                    

      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):                                          
          if request.GET.get('unsubscribe') is True:                                    
              request.user.email_me = False                                             
              request.user.save()                                                       
          elif request.GET.get('unsubscribe') is False:                                 
              request.user.email_me = True                                              
              request.user.save()                                                       
          self.object = self.get_object()                                               
          context = self.get_context_data(object=self.get_object)                       
          return self.render_to_response(context)
```

This works fine when I use the link from an email. However, when I try to test this code, the test client doesn't follow the overridden `get` method in the `DetailView`; it goes through a `get` method specific to the test client/suite. How do I test this overridden `get` method? Here is my test code:

```
def test_unsubscribe_link(self):                                                
    url = reverse('profile_page', args=[self.member.pk])                        
    self.assertTrue(self.member.email_me)                                       
    response = self.client.get(url, {'unsubscribe': True})                      
    self.assertFalse(self.member.email_me)                                      
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)                                 
    self.assertContains(response.content, "Email me reminder notifications: No")
```

Comment: I think you might want to check your if statement. Get gives you the content of the dictionary, not necessarily True or False. You can check without the "is True" part. Or even better "if 'unsubscribe' in request.GET". BTW, you are also testing twice for the same condition in the else (no need).

Comment: @Pynchia thanks - the URL I use from an email contains a query string - `?unsubscribe=True` or `?unsubscribe=False`. The second is to re-subscribe people. The issue I'm facing is that the test client doesn't seem to go through this overridden `get` method I've put into the `DetailView`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the method isn't called, the problem is that you don't reload the data from the database.

A proper test would look something like this:

```
def test_unsubscribe_link(self):                                                
    url = reverse('profile_page', args=[self.member.pk])
    self.assertTrue(Member.objects.get(pk=self.member.pk).email_me)
    response = self.client.get(url, {'unsubscribe': 'True'})
    # Reload data from database
    self.assertFalse(Member.objects.get(pk=self.member.pk).email_me)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertContains(response.content, "Email me reminder notifications: No")
```

Note that, even though you pass `True` or `False` in your query string, when you receive the value from `request.GET` it will always be a string. You'll need to check for the literal strings `'True'` and `'False'`, or you need to somehow convert the value to a boolean.

Comment: you're right, thanks! Turns out your fix plus using `RequestFactory` fixed the entire problem. My question was closer to the `RequestFactory` issue but this was also an error.

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory